# Trailhead: Creating Validation Rules

Tags: validation, trailhead

I am stuck on this challenge. I have attempted to create validation rules as instructed, but I keep getting the error below.

[image]

Here is a screen shot of my validation rule:

[image]

I have tried different suggestions from other posts and it doesnt seem to work. I will appreciate help on this.

Comment: Add one more condition in this rule. It should fire when mailingpostalcode is not blank

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure I under would you mean by "it should fire" and require further clarification on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard Required Field error, probably created from a different trailhead challenge. Go to the MailingPostalCode__c custom field, and remove the Required attribute.

Comment: Spot on!!!!  Thanks for saving loads of frustration!!